# Should I notify user if link has been expired?

Tags: email, coldfusion, token, password-recovery

I'm creating logic for password recovery. User will submit request by providing their email address. Then email will be sent with more information that includes the link with the url parameter. This parameter is `token` created with ColdFusion `createUUID()` method. When user clicks on the link first thing to check is if url parameter exist then if it's valid token. The next step is to check if token exists in Database and pull `Expiration` value/timestamp. Here is example of my code:

```
<cfscript>
    if (structKeyExists(url,"token") AND isValid("uuid", url.token) AND len(trim(url.token)) EQ 35){
        cfstoredproc( procedure="ckToken", datasource=dsn ) {
            cfprocparam( maxlength=35, null=!len(trim(url.token)), cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar", dbvarname="@Token", value=trim(url.token) );
            cfprocresult( name="Result" );

        }

        if( dateCompare(now(), Result.Expires, "s") == -1 ){
            writeOutput("Link Valid Current: " & now() & " Expires: " & Result.Expires);
            //include = "form.html";
        }else{
            writeOutput("Link Invalid Current: " & now() & " Expires: " & Result.Expires);
        }
    }else{

    }
</cfscript>
```

If link is valid and not expired user will be directed to `.html` that has form with the password input field. If link has been expired I'm wondering should notify the user with the message or kick them back to the login page? I'm not sure if there is standard process for this kind of situation. If anyone have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: I think just telling them in the email that the link will expire in 30 minutes is sufficient. Excess email traffic isn't a good thing for either your email server or your user's inboxes.

Comment: @Shawn Can you please clarify what do you mean by `Excess email traffic isn't a good thing for either your email server or your user's inboxes`. What you suggest when they click on the expired link, just do not show anything?

Comment: Having your email server send mail makes more traffic for it to handle. So if it doesn't need to, then don't make it. And your users begin to ignore emails if they don't deem them important. Plus, there is a bandwidth impact (though probably slight). If you already tell them the link will expire, you don't need to again remind them that it's expired.

Comment: @Shawn I do not think that we understand each other. If you read my question you will understand that I'm not trying to send another email if link expired. Code above is triggered once user clicks on the link. Then I check if link is still valid. If it's not, I was wondering should I show message on the screen something like `This link has been expired.`. I hope this helps better to understand my question.

Comment: Yes, that's clearer. If the link is expired when they try to use it, then yes tell them it's expired and kick them back to a login, or better yet include the expiration message on the login page and tell them to try again. If it's valid, then have them verify their identity with some other piece of information, and if they pass then let them reset. I wouldn't bother with display to them when the key is active; just tell them it's expired or let them reset. Give the person on the other end as little information as they absolutely need. And log reset requests.